# How to get a certain element in a list of lists?

Tags: java, list, properties

I want to be able to get a particular element in a list.  However, that list is contained in another list.  The reason so, is that I read in a properties file, with keys having more than one value assigned to it separated by commas.  I create a list for each key and its values, and add it to another list which contains multiple lists for each key and its values.

```
# Menu properties file

menuEntryPoint=0
indent=\t\t\t
lines=---------------------------------------------------------

mainMenu=M a i n  M e n u
0.0=First Sub Menu, openMenu(1)
0.1=Second Sub Menu, openMenu(2)
0.2=Third Sub Menu, openMenu(3)

1=First Sub Menu
1.0=Execute this command, executeCommand(...)
1.1=Execute another command, executeCommand(...)
1.2=Execute other command, openMenu(A)

2=First Sub Menu
2.0=Execute this command, executeCommand(...)
2.1=Execute another command, executeCommand(...)
2.2=Execute other command, openMenu(A)

3=First Sub Menu
3.0=Execute this command, executeCommand(...)
3.1=Execute another command, executeCommand(...)
3.2=Execute other command, openMenu(A)
```

Below is code I wrote to print it to the screen:

```
List<List<String>> menuProperties = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

public void configMenuDisplayProperties() throws IOException {

    Date date = new Date();
    Properties menuProp = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Test\\menu.properties");
    menuProp.load(in);

    //Create list of lists for properties
    menuProperties.add(getPropertyList(menuProp, "0"));
    menuProperties.add(getPropertyList(menuProp, "1"));
    menuProperties.add(getPropertyList(menuProp, "2"));
    menuProperties.add(getPropertyList(menuProp, "3"));

    System.out.println(date.toString() + "\t\t" + menuProp.getProperty("developmentArea") + "\n\n");
    System.out.println(menuProp.getProperty("indent") + menuProp.getProperty("mainMenu") + "\n");

        for (Enumeration<?> e = menuProp.propertyNames(); e.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            String name = (String)e.nextElement();
            String value = menuProp.getProperty(name);
            if (name.startsWith(menuProp.getProperty("menuEntryPoint"))) {
                System.out.println(menuProp.getProperty("indent") + name + "\t" + menuProp.getProperty(name));
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Mon Jun 08 13:39:43 EDT 2015        


        M a i n  M e n u

        0.2 Third Sub Menu, openMenu(C)
        0.1 Second Sub Menu, openMenu(2)
        0.0 First Sub Menu, openMenu(1)
```

How exactly can I print out a certain value of a key that is in a list of lists?  I am trying to get my output to look like this, but I'm having trouble doing so.

```
Mon Jun 08 13:39:43 EDT 2015        


        M a i n  M e n u

        0.0 First Sub Menu
        0.1 Second Sub Menu
        0.2 Third Sub Menu
```

I tried doing the following

```
System.out.println(menuProp.getProperty("indent") + name + "\t" + menuProp.getProperty(name));
```

But I am getting the first output you see... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are using Java 7 or above ?

Comment: @OSryx This needs to be compatible with JRE 1.5.0 and not higher..... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below quick code based solution, there is no such API based solution which can meet your requirement.

If you want to get all the 1st comma values then use `HashMap<String, String> indexedHashMap = getValueBashedOnIndex(hashMap, 1);`, and if 3rd comma values then use `HashMap<String, String> indexedHashMap = getValueBashedOnIndex(hashMap, 3);`
Basically second parameter of `getValueBashedOnIndex` is for which index value you want.

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static void readPropertiesFile() {
    ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.cgi.tmi.utils.test");
    Enumeration<String> keys = rb.getKeys();
    HashMap<String, String[]> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = keys.nextElement();
        String value = rb.getString(key);
        //System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
        hashMap.put(key, value.split(","));
    }
    HashMap<String, String> indexedHashMap = getValueBashedOnIndex(hashMap, 3);
    Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = indexedHashMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private static HashMap<String, String> getValueBashedOnIndex(HashMap<String, String[]> hashMap, int i) {
    HashMap<String, String> indexedHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Iterator<Entry<String, String[]>> it = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        String[] strArr = (String[]) pair.getValue();
        String value = "";
        try {
            value = strArr[(i-1)];
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        indexedHashMap.put((String) pair.getKey(), value);
    }
    return indexedHashMap;
}
```

test.properties

```
menuEntryPoint=0
indent=\t\t\t
lines=---------------------------------------------------------

mainMenu=M a i n  M e n u
0.0=First Sub Menu, openMenu(1)
0.1=Second Sub Menu, openMenu(2)
0.2=Third Sub Menu, openMenu(3)

1=First Sub Menu
1.0=Execute this command, executeCommand(...)
1.1=Execute another command, executeCommand(...)
1.2=Execute other command, openMenu(A)

2=First Sub Menu
2.0=Execute this command, executeCommand(...)
2.1=Execute another command, executeCommand(...)
2.2=Execute other command, openMenu(A)

3=First Sub Menu
3.0=Execute this command, executeCommand(...)
3.1=Execute another command, executeCommand(...)
3.2=Execute other command, openMenu(A)

test=test1,test2,test3,test1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> menuProperties = new HashMap();
```

You can store your properties in the map (key, list of values):

```
menuProperties.put("key", mylistofvalues);
```

You can use `get()` to get the property:

```
ArrayList<String> tempList = menuProperties.get("mykey");
```